# User-defined format in SAS

Tags: sas, format

I have this code here, but it does not work as expected:

```
data disease;
input diagcode$;
datalines;
350
290
800
;
run;

proc format;
value $codetwo
'350' = 'Malaria'
'290' = 'Social Anxiety Disorder'
'800' = 'Leg Injury'
;
run;

data diseasereal;
set disease;
diagdesc = put(diagcode, $codetwo.);
run;
```

Desired output:

| diagcode | diagcodedesc |
| --- | --- |
| 350 | Malaria |
| 290 | Social Anxiety Disorder |
| 800 | Leg Injury |

Current output:

| diagcode | diagcodedesc |
| --- | --- |
| 350 | 350 |
| 290 | 290 |
| 800 | 800 |

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong with the code you posted.

Your actual values of DIAGCODE must be different than the value the FORMAT is looking for.  For example if I create DIAGCODE values with leading spaces:

```
data disease;
  input diagcode $char4.;
datalines;
350
 350
290
 290
800
 800
;
```

Then I get that result for the values with leading spaces.

```
OBS    diagcode    diagdesc

 1       350       Malaria
 2        350       350
 3       290       Social Anxiety Disorder
 4        290       290
 5       800       Leg Injury
 6        800       800
```

Look at the values in the normal LISTING output instead of ODS output, because ODS output does not display the leading spaces.

[image]

Or use the $QUOTE or $HEX format to better see what is actually in the variable.